# Unite Columns but only if no column has NA or blank

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to unite two columns using `tidyverse`, but only and only if none of the columns have any NA or blanks.

Any ideas?

```
df <- expand.grid(x = c(1, NA), y = c(2, NA))   
df  

df <- df %>% unite("new", x, y, sep = ", ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)   
df
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the given example?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function to do this.  Subset the data based on the columns that are need for `unite`, check if there are `any` NA elements in that columns, and `if` present, then don't do the `unite` or `else` `unite` them

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(data, cols){
        v1 <- data %>%
            summarise_at(vars(cols), ~ any(is.na(.)|.=="")) %>%
            unlist %>%
            sum
     if(v1 ==0){ data %>%
                 unite(new, cols, sep, ",", remove = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE) } else data
  }
f1(df, c('x', 'y'))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
cols <- c('x', 'y')
i1 <- sum(colSums(is.na(df[cols])|df[cols] == "")) == 0
```

and use the condition with `i1` to `unite` or `paste` those columns

```
 df$new <- if(i1) do.call(paste, c(df[cols], sep=",")) else NULL
```

Comment: Function doesnt seem to be working. Can you please check

Comment: @mike For me, it is working for the data you provided